# Second windows installation not showing up

Tags: windows, multi-boot

I had installed Windows on my SSD, but after a lot of customisation and registry tweaks, it was messed up. So I wanted a clean slate, so I installed windows on my HDD too. (Second partition). The first and the second installation both boot up fine, but the second installation can't see the first one's drive and vice-versa. What can I do so both of the drives show up so I can transfer files? (The drive doesn't show up in disk management.)

Answer (score 1):

These partitions probably don't have drive letters assigned. Since you haven't specified which version of Windows you use, here's a general guide that will work for anything between Vista and Windows 10.

1. Press the Windows key and type `diskmgmt.msc`. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. *Disk Management* window will show up. You should see both disks with their respective partitions.
2. Right-click a partition in question and select *Change drive letter and paths* from the menu.
3. Click *Add* and choose a drive letter. Click OK. The drive should appear immediately.

Repeat this procedure for all missing drives.

Comment: It's also important to know that when you do this, the drive may not boot properly anymore. Which in your case may be ok.

Comment: @JustAGrump Do you have any reference or source for that? I've never heard that assining a drive letter will make the partition unbootable. I'm pretty much certain that I've had drive-letter-partitions before which were very well bootable.

Comment: The Drive doesn't show up in Disk Management.

Answer (score 0):

According to your problem, by default, the partition is hidden to protect your OS.

1. You can open **This PC- file option- view**, you can click **show hidden files, folders or drivers**.
2. Or  I think it may be also related to the file system that your disk is not compatible with. 
   I hope this advice works for you and if there is any question, please free to comment below.